# how to get suppliers name from 3 joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables
The first table of suppliers
The second table of parts
The third table is the suppliers of parts

I want to find the names of the suppliers whose city is the same as the city of the red piece.
please help.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb67A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inner join like below:

```
select sname from S inner join sp on s.s#=sp.s#
inner join p on sp.p#=p.p# and s.city=p.city
```

To get all the suppliers whose city is same as product 'red'.

```
  select sname from S inner join sp on s.s#=sp.s#
    inner join p on sp.p#=p.p# and s.city=p.city and p.pname='red'
```

Comment: thanks @kazi-mohammad-ali-nur I'm sorry I changed my questions

Comment: I want to find the names of the suppliers whose city is the same as the city of the red piece. please help.

Comment: is red piece  pname of a product?

Comment: Mohammad Ali NurYes, each piece has P #, Pname, Status, City, and the meaning of city in table P is the location of the piece.
I want to get suppliers whose city is the same as the city of the red piece

An attached image

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @  Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur   thanks 